# Multiple range of rows deletion in R

Tags: r, delete-row

Let's say I have

```
v <- matrix(seq(150), 50, 3)
k <- c(10, 40)
delta <- 5
```

How can I delete the 10-delta to 10+delta rows and 40-delta to 40+delta rows simultaneously?

I used `vnew <- v[-((k-delta):(k+delta)),]` but it seems that the command only delete using the first element of k (which is 10) and does not delete the 40-delta to 40+delta rows. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Oh and I will need to put this inside a loop where `k` is being updated in each iteration, so `v[c(-{(10-delta):(10+delta)},-{(40-delta):(40+delta)}),]` won't work.

Comment: `-c(sapply(seq(k), function(i) (k[i]-delta):(k[i]+delta)))`

Comment: are there always 2 elements in k?

Comment: Does `delta` change in each iteration? If not you can use something like: `d <- -delta:delta; for (...) {  ... vnew <- v[-(rep(k, each=length(d)) + d)] ...}`

Comment: Delta doesn't change and the number of elements in k is growing in each iteration.

Comment: Thank you, Richard Scriven. It works!

Answer (score 1):

Richard Scriven's answer only returns the indexes `10-delta:10+delta` and `40-delta:40+delta` of the lines to be removed from v. To effectly do it, you must combined it with what you tried like this:

`v[-c(sapply(seq(k), function(i) (k[i]-delta):(k[i]+delta))), ]`

or shorter but dirtier(?): `v[-sapply(seq(k), function(i) (k[i]-delta):(k[i]+delta)), ]`

Answer (score 1):

If `k` is growing in each iteration and `delta` doesn't change I would suggest the following:

```
d <- -delta:delta

for (...) { 
# ... 
vnew <- v[-(rep(k, each=length(d)) + d),]
# ...
}
```

For your example:

```
d <- -5:5
k <- c(10, 40)
rep(k, each=length(d)) + d
# [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
```

EDIT: a benchmark of both solutions:

```
library("rbenchmark")

idx1 <- function(k, delta) {
  d <- -delta:delta

  lapply(seq_along(k), function(i) {
    rep(k[1:i], each=length(d)) + d
  })
}

idx2 <- function(k, delta) {
  lapply(seq_along(k), function(i) {
    c(sapply(1:i, function(ii) {
      (k[ii]-delta):(k[ii]+delta)
    }))
  })
}

set.seed(1)
k <- sample(1e3, 1e2)
delta <- 5

all.equal(idx1(k, delta), idx2(k, delta))
# [1] TRUE

benchmark(idx1(k, delta), idx2(k, delta), order="relative", replications=100)
#             test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1 idx1(k, delta)          100   0.174    1.000     0.172        0          0         0
# 2 idx2(k, delta)          100   1.579    9.075     1.576        0          0         0
```